# Finding and storing zip code when user enters my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to create a website that automatically retrieves the zip code of the user so when they enter my site the zip code of that user is stored into my database. How would I go about researching this topic?

Comment: https://www.zipcodeservices.com/

Answer (score 1):

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uqutuc/2/edit)

(HTML5) ...where the user must agree to share it's location. (of course.)
Try on mobile, it's amazingly accurate ;)

Comment: Maybe doesnt work accurately in all countries , its showing me wrong in India on mobile iOS

Comment: @ChandraSekharWalajapet than you need to move to Croatia! ;)

Comment: may be Croatian ISP/Mobile networks setting up in India might be a lucrative business :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is reverse geocoding.
You see an example here.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding